# How to move ImageView to another ImageView Android Animation

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-imageview

Anyone know how i can move an imageview to another imageview ?

[image]

im thinking at this kind of method, or maybe is another one that i dont know... no problem, im glad to learn it

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="75%p" />
```

i know that fromXDelta (is the starting position) and the toXDelta is the possition where should arrive.. but? how i can know what is my starting position and arrive position looking at my picture example?

Added details:

There are 4 different layouts in here, but only 3 are with weight value. 
The bar from top where are buttons is a layout but not have weight like the rest.

So laying cards from up are in the layout1
My desired position to arrive are in the layout2
Playing cards from down are in the layout3

Also i use onClick methods in xml not onClickListeners. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this programmatically like this :

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final View target = findViewById(R.id.target);
    final View viewToMove = findViewById(R.id.viewToMove);

    viewToMove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            translate(viewToMove, target);
        }
    });
}

private void translate(View viewToMove, View target) {
    viewToMove.animate()
            .x(target.getX())
            .y(target.getY())
            .setDuration(1000)
            .start();
}
```

Here the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/target"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viewToMove"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but... this method is not working... i need to move the first playing card to the imageview where the arrow end.

after using yout code implemented like this in my app:

ImageView poz1Inamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.inamic_pozitia1);
        ImageView cartePusaInamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cartePusaInamic);

        
        poz1Inamic.animate()
                .x(cartePusaInamic.getX())
                .y(cartePusaInamic.getY())
                .setDuration(1000)
                .start();

imageview dont go to my desired view

Comment: Please, add more details about your view hierarchy. Is inamic_pozitia1 and cartePusaInamic are in the same layout ?

Comment: added the requested details

Comment: Ok, just put inamic_pozitia1 and cartePusaInamic in the same parent layout (I suggest a RelativeLayout in your case)

Comment: im sorry i cant put them in the same layouts.. need to be separated

Comment: your code works (but only in the same layout), soo i need to modify all my xml... thanks man.

Comment: @CristianBabarusi How to do it when views are in different layout ? Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly i have succeded with the help of user Francois L.

Was a lot of work to do, i don't say no, because i needed to redesign all my layouts, but this is no problem cause i learned something new and i appreciate all the help i can receive.

If anyone want to move a view (any type of view, imageview, buttonview, textview etc ) to another view it is necessary that both views to be in the same layout, that is the most important part.

And the code to achieve this is:

```
//here is the part of initialization
    ImageView poz1Inamic = (ImageView) findViewById(inamic_pozitia1);
    ImageView poz1InamicSpateCarte = (ImageView) findViewById(inamic_pozitia1spatecarte);

    //other code
    poz1InamicSpateCarte.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //here is the initialization of the arrive position
    ImageView cartePusaInamic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cartePusaInamic);

    //the code for moving from start position to arrive position
    poz1Inamic.animate()
            .x(cartePusaInamic.getX())
            .y(cartePusaInamic.getY())
            .setDuration(333)
            .start();
```